# Displaying a Walkthrough using ARKit in ios

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arimageanchor

I have got a requirement of a walkthrough of a medical device through ARKit. The requirement is like, we have to feed the images of the device to the app to train it about the device. Then once we show the ARKit app over the medical device, it should show a walkthrough of the medical device in the app's camera. It should highlight each button of the device and describe about it. I have been trying it around with the World Tracking and Image Tracking. Can someone guide me through with some links or so?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what I am understanding is you need to detect the **medical machine** which itself a **3D object** so what you can do is **Apple** itself provide a scanner app to make a 3D model of an object (below is the download link)

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects

Which will give you the **.arobject** file after successful scanning

and also you need to create a 3d file of the medical machine with a complete description of it or .dae file of the same medical machine using some designing tool to show in SCNScene after successful detection of the object.

Below are the reference link tutorial on how to implement the same:

> https://blog.usejournal.com/an-introduction-to-arkit-2-object-scanning-68963b9be43a
>
> Video link for same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEqBW3cKF2k

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thankyou for your inputs. Am sure this could help me. But the user story i have got is, I will be given just the images of the medical device. So by any chance, is it possible to achieve this by training our app with the images of the device? I tried Image Tracking in the link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience. I have also enabled feature points with sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]. But I am not sure how to use the feature points and use it to overlay content on each button of the device.

Comment: Can you download the sample project from the apple link and guide me on using the images, please?